# Why does Heroku think everything is up-to-date when it isn't?

Tags: git, heroku

On Heroku I have a production app and I know have a staging app:

```
$ heroku list
=== My Apps
testivate
testivate-staging
```

I have remotes for each:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:testivate.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:testivate.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:testivate-staging.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:testivate-staging.git (push)
```

A few days I go, a deployment broke my production app, so I used `heroku rollback`, finally created the staging app I am using now, and pushed my code to the staging app, presumably with `git push staging master`. (This was a few days ago but I'm pretty sure that's what I did.)

It's all working now on my staging app, so I'm trying to push my code to my production app.

However, Heroku keeps telling me that my production app is already up-to-date:

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git add .
$ git add -u
$ git commit -m "trying to commit"
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

$ git remote show staging
* remote staging
  Fetch URL: git@heroku.com:testivate-staging.git
  Push  URL: git@heroku.com:testivate-staging.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

$ git remote show heroku
* remote heroku
  Fetch URL: git@heroku.com:testivate.git
  Push  URL: git@heroku.com:testivate.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

I know that Heroku is wrong however, because there are some clear-as-day changes to my views which you can see in my local code and on the staging server, but not on my live production app.

For example, compare the "back" link that is correctly [here](http://testivate-staging.herokuapp.com/login) in my staging app, but not [here](http://www.testivate.com/login) in my production app.

How do I get Heroku to update my production app as I want?

Thanks,

Steven.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `heroku releases` to get an idea of what state/commit the production app is in?

Comment: Thanks, yes, the answer was to rollback to the release immediately prior to the rollback.

Comment: @steven_noble Hey, if you have solved your question it is perfectly acceptable to [post an answer and accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) :)

Comment: Yes, by posting your answer you remove the question from the unanswered queue and make the solution more visible to future visitors :)

Answer (score 17):

Are you sure you're referring to the correct branch? Here's the syntax of the actual command:

```
git push heroku <the branch you wish to push>:<the branch on the heroku server you wish to push to>
```

So if you're used to running

```
git push heroku master
```

and you checkout and commit to a branch other than master, running `git push heroku master` will push your unchanged **master** branch. Instead, run

```
git push heroku the_branch_i_changed:master
```

Comment: `git push heroku the_branch_i_changed` is almost there, but you're leaving out the fact that you have to tell the Heroku remote that you still want to push to *it's* `master` branch (Heroku will only deploy from the `master` branch). So it should be: `git push heroku the_branch_i_changed:master`.

Comment: @redhotvengeance Yeah you're dead right, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I made a different mistake with the same outcome (Ruby on Rails specific):

My local site displayed my new logo image, the heroku site displayed the old logo image. Despite this, I kept seeing the message: "nothing to commit (working directory clean)".

I had forgotten to recompile assets before pushing:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Hope that saves someone else the time I wasted!