# Why am I unable to push my app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I haven't been able to get Heroku to update my app for some reason. This is the first app I've had problems with this happening. I've tried a couple different methods, but everything I've tried just says in the command "everything is up to date." and when I check heroku, it's just an early version of my app. Any idea why it won't update on Heroku?

**Here is what I've tried:**

```
$ bundle exec rake test
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "..."  
$ git checkout master 
$ git merge blah 
$ bundle exec rake test
$ git push
$ git push heroku 
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

**and I've also tried this as well:**

```
$ git status  
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "..."
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run db:migrate
```

**Heres the git status:**

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Here's trying to force it**

```
$ git push heroku master --force
Everything up-to-date
```

**Here's with git remote -v**

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/stupidapp1.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/stupidapp1.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Tyrantt47/stupidapp1.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Tyrantt47/stupidapp1.git (push)
```

Comment: Check if it help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574304/why-does-heroku-think-everything-is-up-to-date-when-it-isnt

Comment: Try [heroku is telling "everything up to date"](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN541IN542&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=heroku+is+telling+%22everything+up+to+date%22&spell=1) each search result.

Comment: I just tried: $ git push heroku log-in-log-out:master, and again it said everything was up to date. but nothing has changed. and my changes are night and day.

Comment: Are you sure you are pushing the correct branch? Can you edit your question with the output of "git status"?

Comment: @ThomasO I updated the question with the git status. it says im on the master branch and everything is up to date.

Comment: Try forcing it: git push heroku origin --force

Comment: @ThomasO This is what i got when i tried it: `$ git push heroku origin --force
error: src refspec origin does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/blah.git'`

Comment: Sorry, wrong branch, the command should be: git push heroku master --force

Comment: @ThomasO `git push heroku master --force  Everything up-to-date`

Comment: @ThomasO thanks for the help so far. Do you have any other suggestions I could try? I gotta catch some sleep but I'll try them after work tomorrow!

Comment: Try git remote -v.  Does that path for 'heroku' match the repository for the heroku app?

Comment: @Curtis can you tell me what is in your .git/config if on linux or mac cat .git/config in your root of your app.

Comment: @Jay Just did it, i posted  results in question

Comment: @Spasm im on mac, i see .gitignore and config.ru.. though im not sure thats what you are talking about

Comment: @Curtis there is a hidden .git folder in that there is a config file.... from that I will be able to see if you are all configured correctly. Command is on your terminal prompt in your apps root:: $ cat .git/config

Comment: @Curtis $ git branch will also be useful. I suspect you have not merged changes from a branch ? I see on your github you have a branch "static-pages" which is ahead of your master branch. I can show you how to merge them or even do it all through github

Comment: @Spasm I noticed that too and when I try merging it, i get "Already up-to-date" but yeah, ill take any help at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curtis, I feel like this answer could be judged as the antithesis of a good dev, but if you have the code you want to deploy checked into version control and locally, why not just push it to a new Heroku app.

If the name of the repository is any indication of the scale of the application, I would say try it and see the results.

Heroku provides good documentation on migrating a database from one app to another and its add-on services are easy to get setup, if either one of those are a concern.

Food for thought...

Comment: yeah, i figured that was ultimately what i was going to do, but i wanted to know what i screwed up, so i can make sure it doesnt happen again. guess ill go ahead with it. So i created a new app, how do i change this one over to the new one?

Comment: was i supposed to fork it? i did that, and all it did was create a copy of the app to a new app. Not sure how this will fix it if the code and whatever is wrong with the app is exactly the same..

Comment: Am I supposed to copy/paste the directory into a new directory for the clone app and set it up with git hub? im kinda lost here

Comment: So i created a new repository and a new heroku app, copied the code over, and on the local server, everything seems to work fine... but on the heroku side, the app is at the EXACT same place where it wouldnt update past on the other app. I have been trying to figure this out for hours. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the syntax is

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Comment: "everything is up to date"